# Is it possible to get items from DynamoDB where the primary key ends with a given string?

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk

Is it possible, using the AWS Ruby SDK (or just DynamoDB in general), to get an item or items from a table that uses a primary key only, and where that primary key ends with a certain string?

I haven't come across anything in the docs that explicitly answers this question, either in the ruby ddb docs or the general docs for ddb. I'm not saying the question is not answered, but if it is, I can't find it.

If it is possible, could someone provide an example for ruby or link to the docs where an example exists?

Comment: I dare not posting an answer, as I just have a theory, but - since DDB is all about the performance (since the storage is nearly free) - depending on the primary key length, it may be feasible to have another PK (in a global secondary index) with the values reversed, so you can apply the starts with thing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you would want to use the Query method on the SDK to find the items your looking for. It seems that "EndsWith" is not available as a comparison operator in the SDK though. So you would need to use CONTAINS and then check your results locally.

This should lead to the best performance, letting DynamoDb do the initial heavy lifting and then further pruning the results once you receive them.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkforruby/api/Aws/DynamoDB/Client.html#query-instance_method

Comment: That's exactly what I'm looking for. It's a shame there's only a "starts with" comparison operator, but like you said, I can take care of that myself.

Comment: You should highlight in your answer that this will force a scan and breaks things like pagination using limits and last evaluated key.

Answer (score 5):

Although @Ryan is correct and this can be done with `query`, just bear in mind that you're doing a "full-table-scan" here. That might be OK for a one-time job but probably not the best practice for a routine task (and of course not as a part of your API calls).

If your use-case involves quickly finding objects based on their suffix in a specific field, consider extracting this suffix (assuming it's a fixed-size suffix) as another field and have a secondary index on that one. If you want to query arbitrary length suffixes, I would create a lookup table and update it with possible suffixes (or some of them, to save some calls, and then filter when querying).